# label inside a div selection using nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have read about [CSS3 :nth-child() Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) I made this [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/LwxyLc45/)

**Html**

```
<body>
<div> <label>dsdf</label></div>
<div>seconddiv</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
label.nth-child(1){
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Why is the background of the label not red?

Comment: It is a pseudo-class and not a class. You need to use it as `label:nth-child(1)` and `label.nth-child(1)`.

Comment: `.` is for class selector, for pseudo selector use `:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nth-child()` pseudo selector needs `:` instead of `.` before it.

```
label:nth-child(1){
    background: #ff0000;
}
```